# Simple 2d texture render

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I've been trying for the last two and a half hours to get a simple 2D texture renderer working using opengl es on ios.  I've tried following [this](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-part-6_25.html') tutorial to no avail. I've checked my gl errors , checked my triangle ordering, even tried switching back to ES1 to use the fixed function pipeline to absolutely no avail.  I'm at a complete loss here, what is going wrong?  For completeness' sake, here is my setup and draw code:

```
- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    GLenum err = 0;

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GL_Target"];
    if (image == nil)
        NSLog(@"Do real error checking here");

    GLuint width = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage);
    GLuint height = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    void *imageData = malloc( height * width * 4 );
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( imageData, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );
    CGContextClearRect( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ) );
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0, height - height );
    CGContextDrawImage( context, CGRectMake( 0, 0, width, height ), image.CGImage );

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    CGContextRelease(context);

    free(imageData);

    effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
}


-(void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
 GLfloat rot = 0.0;

    GLenum err = 0;

    glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    static const GLfloat vertices[] = {
        -1.0,  1.0, -0.0,
         1.0,  1.0, -0.0,
        -1.0, -1.0, -0.0,
         1.0, -1.0, -0.0
    };
    static const GLfloat normals[] = {
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0, 1.0
    };
    static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
        0.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0,
        0.0, 0.0,
        1.0, 0.0
    };

    glLoadIdentity();
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glRotatef(rot, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    CHECK_GL_ERR();

    static NSTimeInterval lastDrawTime;
    if (lastDrawTime)
    {
        NSTimeInterval timeSinceLastDraw = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - lastDrawTime;
        rot+=  60 * timeSinceLastDraw;
    }
    lastDrawTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
}
```

**EDIT**

After scrapping that approach, I am now trying to mirror [this project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1) because I was actually able to get that to build, run, and render on my machine.  I started by copying the code I thought was important, then copied line by line, then copied entire file contents, then copied entire files, and then created a brand new project, copied over the view controller, sprite, and storyboard files and it still doesn't work.  What part of project setup am I missing that is making new projects not work with 100% the exact same code as a project that does work?

Comment: Is this line correct? CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0, height - height) -- height - height would always be zero... did you mean just -height?

Answer (score 0):

From just that code, it seems you are missing binding the shaders.

```
glUseProgram(program);
```

Also make sure your shaders compile without error when you run the program.

The author of that blog has also a sample OpenGL ES 2.0 project for XCode in github. Please take a look at it, https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff

Comment: But the shader shouldn't be necessary when using fixed function.  Is using fixed function no longer an option?